# how to parallelize cached functions using joblib

Tags: python, multiprocessing, joblib

I would like to paralellize a function that is cached with joblib.Memory
however I get the following error:

```
TypeError: can't pickle function objects
```

Here is the code:

```
import joblib

mem = joblib.Memory(cachedir='/tmp')


@mem.cache
def foo(x):
    # do some complicated task
    return x + 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    f = joblib.delayed(foo)
    res = joblib.Parallel(n_jobs=-2)(f(x) for x in range(100))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using different name for the decorated function like `foo_cached = mem.cache(foo)` instead of decorator. See also https://github.com/joblib/joblib/issues/226